# Can I make this jQuery shorter?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Basically, all I would like to do is to make this a little cleaner so the page loads quicker, is there a way to do this?

My head code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Steve A Tattoo Artist</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond' rel='stylesheet' type="text/css">
<!--[if lt ie 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/styles/ie7.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt ie 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/styles/ie6.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
<link rel="pingback" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/xmlrpc.php" />

<!--DEMO CSS LINKS-->
<link href="http:/www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--FANCY BOX REFS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<!--GALLERIA-->
<script src="/galleria/galleria-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script src="/galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js"></script>
<script>Galleria.loadTheme('/galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');</script>

<!--FANCY BOX JAVA-->
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
/* This is basic - uses default settings */
$("a#single_image").fancybox();

/* Using custom settings */
$("a#inline").fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': true
});

/* Apply fancybox to multiple items */  
$("a.group").fancybox({
    'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
    'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
    'speedIn'       :   600, 
    'speedOut'      :   200, 
    'overlayShow'   :   false
});
});
</script> 

<!--STEVE A DIV-->

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
$("#firstpagename, #firstpagename2").click(function () {
$("div#white").toggle();
$("div#v2black, div#v3black").hide();
});

$("#secondpagename, #secondpagename2").click(function () {
$("div#v2black").toggle();
$("div#white, #v3black").hide();
});

$("#thirdpagename, #thirdpagename2").click(function () {
$("div#v3black").toggle();
$("div#white, #v2black").hide();
});

$(".toggle").click(function(){
      $(".toggle").hide();
      $(this).toggle();
});

});
<!--MAIN TOP NAV SCROLLING-->

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 591) {
        $(".altstevenav:hidden").show();
    }
    else {
        $(".altstevenav:visible").hide();
    }
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 591) {
        $(".topwhiteborder:hidden").show();
    }
    else {
        $(".topwhiteborder:visible").hide();
    }
});
</script>
<!--END OF DEMO CSS LINKS-->

<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Steve A Tattoo Artist &raquo; Feed" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/?feed=rss2" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Steve A Tattoo Artist &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/?feed=comments-rss2" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='jquery.fancybox-css'  href='http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/plugins/fancy-box/jquery.fancybox.css?ver=1.2.6' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/plugins/fancy-box/jquery.fancybox.js?ver=1.2.6'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/plugins/fancy-box/jquery.easing.js?ver=1.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.js?ver=20090102'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 

<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.3.1" />
<link rel='canonical' href='http://www.steveatattooartist.com/' />
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var select = $('a[href$=".bmp"],a[href$=".gif"],a[href$=".jpg"],a[href$=".jpeg"],a[href$=".png"],a[href$=".BMP"],a[href$=".GIF"],a[href$=".JPG"],a[href$=".JPEG"],a[href$=".PNG"]');
        select.attr('rel', 'fancybox');
        select.fancybox();
    });
</script>
    <style type="text/css">.recentcomments a{display:inline !important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}</style>
```

I figured this isn't as neat as it should be and can be tidied up! Any help is appreciated...

Comment: belongs on the code review SE site

Comment: have a little respect when posting code.... all the script and link tags are worthless here and the important part that script refers to, the html, is not displayed

Comment: @MildFuzz: Please don't suggest that, I'm sure they don't want this post in it's current form. I could be wrong, so apologies if this is proper material for Code Review.

Comment: haha, agreed. Didn't really read it

Comment: Yeah people do that all the time it seems ;)

Comment: What is: code review SE site?

And why would you need the html when I only want to see if it can be made shorter? - Direction of help is only what I am after not arrogant replies of "have a little respect when posting code." and belongs elsewhere

Posting all of my head code, thinking it may help. Also, why not direct me in what I should be doing with a link and saying, excuse me mate, you may be confused, this is for elsewhere.

I would like to thank thugsb and thirtydot who helped me with my question even thought it might have been in the wrong place.

Comment: as for the others, stackoverflow is FULL of two types of people none of the comments above helped at all, not doing the site much justice.

Comment: @OwenO'Neill: We would need to see the HTML to truly help you optimize because it's *directly* related to the javascript. You have three functions that look redundant, but without HTML edits (or at least *knowing* what's in the HTML) they can't be changed. If you were only interested in the javascript part, there's no reason to clutter your post with all the other irrelevant info, like your `<head>` tags, `<title>`, CSS, and doctype. This is what you were asked to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bring all your JS into a single script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Galleria.loadTheme('/galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');

jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
  /* This is basic - uses default settings */
  $("a#single_image").fancybox();

  /* Using custom settings */
  $("a#inline").fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': true
  });

  /* Apply fancybox to multiple items */  
  $("a.group").fancybox({
    'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
    'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
    'speedIn'       :   600, 
    'speedOut'      :   200, 
    'overlayShow'   :   false
  });

  // STEVE A DIV
  $("#firstpagename, #firstpagename2").click(function () {
    $("div#white").toggle();
    $("div#v2black, div#v3black").hide();
  });

  $("#secondpagename, #secondpagename2").click(function () {
    $("div#v2black").toggle();
    $("div#white, #v3black").hide();
  });

  $("#thirdpagename, #thirdpagename2").click(function () {
    $("div#v3black").toggle();
    $("div#white, #v2black").hide();
  });

  $(".toggle").click(function(){
    $(".toggle").hide();
    $(this).toggle();
  });


  // MAIN TOP NAV SCROLLING

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 591) {
      $(".altstevenav:hidden, .topwhiteborder:hidden").show();
    }
    else {
      $(".altstevenav:visible, .topwhiteborder:visible").hide();
    }
  });

  var select = $('a[href$=".bmp"],a[href$=".gif"],a[href$=".jpg"],a[href$=".jpeg"],a[href$=".png"],a[href$=".BMP"],a[href$=".GIF"],a[href$=".JPG"],a[href$=".JPEG"],a[href$=".PNG"]');
  select.attr('rel', 'fancybox');
  select.fancybox();
});

</script>
```

You could also combine all your JS libraries (fancybox, galleria, etc.) into a single libraries.js file. And, of course, move the above JS into an external scripts.js file.

Also, you're calling jquery twice, and fancybox twice, so should probably remove one instance of each.

I'm not sure how much WordPress will allow you to optimize, but reducing the number of JS and CSS files would be beneficial. Best practice, you'll want a call to jquery, a libraries.js and a scripts.js, with no other JS (either external or inline).

Comment: cheers guys! Appreciate it big time!

Comment: but not work if i change   var select = jQuery('img[src$=".bmp"],img[src$=".gif"],img[src$=".jpg"],img[src$=".jpeg"],img[src$=".png"],img[src$=".BMP"],img[src$=".GIF"],img[src$=".JPG"],img[src$=".JPEG"],img[src$=".PNG"]');
  select.attr('rel', 'fancybox');
  select.fancybox();